How to prove the sequence of function $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy but not convergent? (Details Below)
Problem
Consider the space $C[-1,1]$, together with the norm defined by $\|f\|_1 = \int_{-1}^1|f|d\lambda$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure). For each $n$ define a function $f_n:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{align*}
    f_n(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        0\quad  &\text{if $-1\leq x\leq 0$},\\
        nx\quad &\text{if $0<x\leq\frac{1}{n}$},\\
        1\quad  &\text{if $\frac{1}{n}<x\leq1$}.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Prove that $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C[-1,1]$. Then show there is now continuous function $f$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n-f\|_1=0$.
My Attempt So Far

Here is my attempt so far to prove the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy:


Let $\epsilon$ be any positive number. We want to show that there is a positive integer $N$ such that $d(f_m,f_n)<\epsilon$ whenever $m\geq N$ and $n\geq N$. Write
\begin{align}
d(f_m,f_n) &= \|f_m-f_n\|_1\\
&= \int_{-1}^1|f_m-f_n|d\lambda\\
&= \int|f_m-f_n|\chi_{[a,b]}d\lambda\\
&= \sup\left\{\int hd\lambda:h\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ h\leq|f_m-f_n|\chi_{[a,b]}\right\}\\
&\dots
\end{align}

I got stuck here, don't know how to proceed next.

For the nonexistence of a continuous function, I drew a diagram. I can see that the function would eventually goes to
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0\quad &\text{if $-1\leq x\leq0$},\\
1\quad &\text{if $0<x\leq1$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
which is clearly not continuous. But I don't know how to prove it rigorously.


Could someone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!

You may need to invoke Vitali Theorem: $(f_n)$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$-norm implies that there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ that converges to $0$ pointewise a.e. (provied that we are working with finite measure, which is the case since $\lambda$ is finite on $[-1,1]$).

@DannyPak-KeungChan Thanks lot for your comment and answer! I haven't learned Vitali (Convergence; I think) Theorem yet, but I will come back when I get there.

Since the sequence $(f_n)$ is simple enough, we do not need to invoke Vitali Theorem nor even Lebesgue measure theory (i.e., working within the framework of Riemann integral is good enough). You may read my other proof.

It is false that "Since $[-1,1]$ is compact, the $L^{1}$-norm
is equivalent to $L^{\infty}$-norm."
The following is a famous counter-example (in probability theory). (one may argue that the given $f_n$ are not continuous, but we can always smooth out the function at the edge.)
Let $f_{1}=1_{[0,1]}$, $f_{2}=1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$, $f_{3}=1_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$,
$f_{4}=1_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]}$, $f_{5}=1_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4}]}$,
$f_{6}=1_{[\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{4}]},$$f_{7}=1_{[0,\frac{1}{8}]}$,
$\ldots$.
Clearly $||f_{n}||_{1}\rightarrow0$ but $||f_{n}||_{\infty}=1$ for
all $n$.

The correct way to solve the problem:
Firstly, we show that $(f_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect
to the $L^{1}$-norm. Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m<n$. By direct
calculation, we have that
$$
|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\leq2\cdot1_{[0,\frac{1}{m}]}(x).
$$
That is, $|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|$ vanishes if $x\in[-1,0]\cup[\frac{1}{m},1]$
and $|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\leq2$ if $x\in[0,\frac{1}{m}]$. Therefore,
$\int_{-1}^{1}|f_{n}-f_{m}|\,d\lambda\leq\frac{2}{m}$. Hence, $(f_{n})$
is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the $||\cdot||_{1}$-norm.
Next, we show that $(f_{n})$ does not converges to any element in
$C[-1,1]$. Prove by contradiction. Suppose there exists $f\in C[-1,1]$
such that $\int_{-1}^{1}|f_{n}-f|\,d\lambda\rightarrow0$. By Vitali
Theorem, there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ and a measurable
set $A\subseteq[-1,1]$ with $\lambda([-1,1]\setminus A)=0$ such
that for each $x\in A$, $|f_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.
(i.e., $f_{n_{k}}-f\rightarrow0$ pointwisely a.e.).
For $x\in A$, clearly, $\lim_{k}f_{n_{k}}(x)=1_{(0,1]}(x)$. Hence,
$f(x)=1_{(0,1]}(x)$ for $x\in A$. Since $f$ is continuous and $\lambda([-1,1]\setminus A)=0$,
it follows that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[-1,1]\setminus A$ too. (For,
$[-1,1]\setminus A$ has measure zero $\Rightarrow$ it cannot contain
any interior point $\Rightarrow$ for each $x\in[-1,1]\setminus A$,
there exists a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $A$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$.
By the continuity of $f$...).
That is, $f=1_{(0,1]}$, which is a contradiction.

Thanks a lot! I haven't learned Vitali Theorem, I wonder if I can proceed as follows: Prove $f_n\to f$: $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\begin{cases}0\quad&\text{if $-1\leq x\leq0$},\1-nx\quad&\text{if $0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{n}$},\0\quad&\text{if $\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq1$}.\end{cases}$$ Then $d(f_n,f)=\int|f_n-f|\chi_{[-1,1]}d\lambda=\int|f_n-f|\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}d\lambda\leq\int1\cdot\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}=\frac{1}{n}$. So for any $\epsilon>0$, let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then $c\geq N$ implies that $d(f_n,f)\leq\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.

(The $f$ is the one defined in the question.) Then prove $f$ is not continuous at $p=0$: Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Then for every $\delta>0$, $|f(x)-f(0)|=1>\frac{1}{2}=\epsilon$ when $x\in[-1,0]$ and $|x-p|<\delta$.

The following is an elementary proof without invoking Vitali Theorem.
Suppose the contrary that there exists $f\in C[-1,1]$ such that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$
with respect to $||\cdot||_{1}$. We go to show that $f(x)=0$ for
all $x\in(-1,0)$. Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that
there exists $x\in(-1,0)$ such that $|f(x)|=c>0$. Since $|f(x)|>\frac{c}{2}$,
by continuity of $f$ at $x$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$|f(y)|>\frac{c}{2}$ for all $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq(-1,0)$.
It follows that $\frac{c}{2}\cdot2\delta\leq\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}|f(y)|\,dy=\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}|f(y)-f_{n}(y)|\,dy\leq\int_{-1}^{1}|f(y)-f_{n}(y)|\,dy=||f-f_{n}||_{1}\rightarrow0$,
which is a contradiction. (In the above, note that $f_{n}(y)=0$ for
all $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.
Next, we show that $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. Prove by contradiction.
Suppose the contrary that there exists $x\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x)\neq1$.
Let $c=|f(x)-1|>0$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x-\delta>0$
and $|f(y)-1|>\frac{c}{2}$ for all $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq(0,1)$.
Choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<x-\delta$. For $n\geq N$, $f_{n}(y)=1$
whenever $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ because $\frac{1}{n}<x-\delta$.
Therefore, for $n\geq N$, $\frac{c}{2}\cdot2\delta\leq\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}|f(y)-1|\,dy=\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}|f(y)-f_{n}(y)|\,dy\leq||f-f_{n}||_{1}\rightarrow0$,
which is also a contradiction.
We conclude that $f(x)=0$ if $x\in(-1,0)$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in(0,1)$.
This shows that $f$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, a contradiction.

Without loss of generality, you can assume $n>m$, then
$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $-1\le x\le0$}\\
(n-m)x & \text{if $0\le x\le1/n$}\\
1-mx & \text{if $1/n\le x\le1/m$}\\
0 & \text{if $1/m\le x\le1$}
\end{cases}$$
You could explicitely compute the integral and show that it goes to $0$ for $m,n\to\infty$. To conclude faster, observe that $|f_n-f_m|\le1$ and it vanishes over $[-1,0]\cup[1/m,1]$, hence
\begin{align}
\|f_n-f_m\|_1=\int_{-1}^1 |f_n-f_m|d\lambda=\int_{0}^{1/m}|f_n-f_m|d\lambda\le\frac{1}{m}\le\frac{1}{N},
\end{align}
that is $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.
Since $[-1,1]$ is compact, the $L^1-$norm is equivalent to the $L^\infty-$norm, but $f_n$ converges pointwise to the function $\chi_{[0,1]}$, which is not continuous, hence it cannot converge to a continuous function uniformly.
Edit: As remarked, it is not true that the $L^1$ and the $L^\infty$ norms coindide on $[-1,1]^\mathbb{R}$, while it is true on $C^0([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$, hence the proof is valid

It is false that ``Since $[-1,1]$ is compact, the $L^{1}$-norm
is equivalent to $L^{\infty}$-norm.'' It is easy to construct a sequence $(f_n)$ such that $||f_n||1\rightarrow 0$ but $||f_n||\infty=1$ for all $n$.

In fact, $(f_n)$ can be chosen such that for $x$-a.e., $\lim_n f_n(x)$ does not exists. See my counter-example

You are right, I was thinking the norm restricted to the continuous functions, but I didn't write it. Thanks for the remark, I edited my answer

I have not touched mathematics for 14 years after I graduated, but
I remember that two norms $||\cdot||{1}$ and $||\cdot||{2}$ are
equivalent on a vector space $X$ iff there exists $C_{1},C_{2}>0$
such that $||\cdot||{1}\leq C{1}||\cdot||{2}$ and $||\cdot||{2}\leq C_{2}||\cdot||{1}$.
Of course, $C{1}$ and $C_{2}$ can be chosen the same by considering
$\max(C_{1},C_{2})$.

On the vector space $C([-1,1])$, we can never find $C>0$ such that
$||f||{\infty}\leq C||f||{1}$ for all $f\in C([-1,1])$ because
$f$ can be chosen as a pulse (the graph is an isosceles triangle
with height $n$ and base $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ around $x=0$ but zero
everywhere), then $||f||{\infty}=n$ while $||f||{1}=\frac{1}{2n}$.
Therefore such $C>0$ does not exist.

In short, $L^1$ norm and $L^\infty$ are not equivalent on $C([-1,1])$

$d(f_n,f)=\tfrac{1}{2n}$ for all $n$ so clearly $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the metric. Since $f_n$ converges in the metric it is Cauchy in the metric. However, the limit function is not in the space of continuous functions, showing the space of continuous functions is not complete in the metric. The sequence converges in the space of integrable functions but not in the space of continuous functions.
You can also show directly that $f_n$ is Cauchy in the metric. When calculating $d(f_n,f_m)$ there is no harm done assuming $n>m$ so can set $n=m+k$. Then $$f_{m+k}(x)-f_{m}(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \mathrm{if}\ -1\leq x\leq0\\
kx & \mathrm{if}\ 0<x\leq\tfrac{1}{m+k}\\
1-mx & \mathrm{if}\ \tfrac{1}{m+k}<x\leq\tfrac{1}{m}\\
0 & \mathrm{if}\ \tfrac{1}{m}<x\leq1
\end{cases}$$ and evaluating the integral you get $d(f_{m+k},d_{m})=\frac{k}{2m(m+k)}<\frac{k}{2mk}<\frac{1}{m}.$ Consequently, $d(f_n,f_m)<\varepsilon$ when $n>m>\tfrac{1}{\varepsilon}.$

Thanks for your help! Quick question: Why is $d(f_n,f)=\frac{1}{2n}$?

My concern is if we want to use Riemann integral, we need to prove that $|f_n-f|\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}$ is continuous at almost every point of $[-1,1]$ (so that we could conclude that $|f_n-f|\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}$ is Riemann integrable, and so it is Lebesgue integrable, and the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals of $|f_n-f|\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}$ coincide). But does the almost-everywhere continuity hold for $|f_n-f|\chi_{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}$?
